# Transforming wildcard user input to tsquery

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, postgresql-10

We have a search input field on our website. We would like to support the following 4 wildcards:

```
1) find results that contain at least one of the two words:
tree apple

2) find results that contain both words:
+tree +apple

3) find results that contain the word tree but not apple:
tree -apple

4) partial match, find results like bartender, barometer, barricade, ...:
bar*
```

We are using the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    v.title,
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(v.title), query) AS rank
FROM
    vid.video v, to_tsquery('<<USER INPUT HERE>>') query
WHERE
    (to_tsvector(v.title) @@ query)
ORDER BY
    rank DESC
```

How can we restructure user's raw input to support all wildcards and ensure compatibility with `to_tsquery` function? Does there exist any existing library for C# which can format user's wildcard input to `tsquery`?

Comment: Can the user use the 4 wildcards in the same search ?

Comment: The wildcard language you use above seems pretty specific to your use - I'm not aware of a general-purpose wildcard language that would be supported by a general C# library etc... This is likely something you'll have to take care of yourself.

Comment: @Philippe Yes, they can all appear in the same search string.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I am leaning toward implementing this by myself as well, but I will have to be careful about edge-cases. That's why I was wondering if there is any existing thoroughly tested library which supports this out-of-the-box.

Comment: The user will write the serach string like that ? `-apple +rabbit +potatoes recipe veget*`

Comment: @Philippe Yes. However, user input is unpredictable, they could also write `[8*)+/2 apple-rabbit____ abc **23sg`.

Comment: You can split the string `var SplittedString = MyString.Split(' ',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` and check if each word strats or end by `- + *`. In the string you give what would you like to have as result search string ? Can you edit your post and give examples of expected results ?